# ¿Como obtener la dirección IP de un dispositivo utilizando Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, programación-móvil

necesito obtener la dirección IP asignada a un dispositivo móvil, ya sea android o Iphone. Ya se que en algunos casos el código para android no es igual que el de IOS.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar obtener la IP del dispositivo por medio del siguiente ejemplo

En Android necesitas requerir dos permisos en el manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

En iOS no es requerido solicitar permisos.
Una vez en tu codigo compartido, puedes utilizar:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No dispositivos con direccion IPv4 encontrados!");
}
```

Tal vez te gustaria validar antes de esto, si el dispositivo tiene una conexion a internet activa.

Esta informacion fue obtenida desde la siguiente pregunta en StackOverflow en Ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address/6803109#6803109